# How to start python thread with control?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am developing my school project and it requires starting threads with control. The following code is a sample that simulates my scenario.

GrandFather has 3 children **[Mike, William, John]** these children are fathers now. so they also have children

```
"Mike": ["Mathew", "Miller"]
"William": ["Willy", "Winson", "Walt"]
"John": ["Jude"]
```

**Father** and **Son** classes are thread classes. GrandFather create Father classes according to their age (order). Then **Father** create his **Sons** classes

but the Requirement is Grandfather should wait until the elder son creates his next sons. (Father can create their sons without any order )

**Example of execution.**

1. **Grandfather** creates **Mike**
2. **Mike** creates **Mathew** and **Miller**
3. **Grandfather** creates **William**
4. **William** creates **Willy, Winson** and **Walt**
5. **Grandfather** creates **John**
6. **John** creates **Jude**

So I have written the following code and it is not working as expected.

```
import threading
import time
from typing import List


class GrandFather:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sons_of_granfather = {1: "Mike", 3: "John", 2: "William"}
        self.sons_of_father = {"Mike": ["Mathew", "Miller"], "William": ["Willy", "Winson", "Walt"], "John": ["Jude"]}
        self.created_next_son = True

    def run(self):
        print(f"{threading.current_thread()}_run()\n")

        sons_in_order = list(self.sons_of_granfather.keys())

        for order in sorted(sons_in_order):
            name = self.sons_of_granfather.get(order)
            children_of_father = self.sons_of_father.get(name)

            father = Father(name, children_of_father, self.created_next_son)
            self.created_next_son = False
            father.start()

            while not self.created_next_son:
                print(self.created_next_son)
                time.sleep(1)


class Father(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name: str, children: List[str], created_next_son: bool):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
        self.created_next_son = created_next_son
        self.setName(self.name)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        print(f"{threading.current_thread()}_run()\n")

        for childName in self.children:
            son = Son(self.name, childName)
            son.start()

        self.created_next_son = True


class Son(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, fatherName, childName):
        super().__init__()
        self.fatherName = fatherName
        self.childName = childName
        self.setName(f"{self.fatherName}_{self.childName}")
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        print(f"{threading.current_thread()}_run()\n")


grandFather = GrandFather()
grandFather.run()
```

I am maintaining a variable to identify when to create a father. but it gives the following output and won't continue because  `self.created_next_son` becomes `True` again

```
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 15276)>_run()
<Father(Mike, started daemon 12536)>_run()
False
<Son(Mike_Mathew, started daemon 10016)>_run()
<Son(Mike_Miller, started daemon 5824)>_run()
```

It remains in the while loop forever. please help me to solve this issue

Comment: This is an utterly bizarre use of threading. `self.created_next_son` is an instance variable. Each instance of `Father` and `GrandFather` have their own version. The while loop will never end because `self.created_next_son` is never changed to `True` once the loop starts. If you need to communicate between threads, use a `threading.Event` object, which is thread-safe and designed for this sort of use.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay, It may be homework that was assigned by an instructor who is clueless about how and why to use threads.

Comment: Re, "Grandfather should wait until..." Python's [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event) class could be of some use. If Grandfather would create an `Event` and pass it in to each of the three Fathers, then Father could `set()` the event after creating the `Son`s, and Grandfather could `wait()` until the event is set and then `clear()` the event to make it ready for the next Father.

Comment: P.S., If you are using Python 2.7, then you could use a [`threading.Semaphore`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html?highlight=semaphore#semaphore-objects) in a similar way: Use `semaphore.acquire()` instead of `event.wait()`, and use `semaphore.release()` instead of `event.set()`. Note: With a semaphore, there will be no need to "clear" it to make it ready for the next Father.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem using **threading.Event**